# Why object variable is not increased?

Tags: javascript

please help solve the problem.

i make class for game with several levels.

```
var Game = function() {
  self = this;

  this.myMove = false;
  this.level = 1;

  this.Start();
};

Game.prototype = {

  Start: function() {
    this.levelInfo();

    $(document).keypress(function(){
      self.level++;
      // game body
      self.Start();
    });
  },     

  levelInfo: function() {
    this.clearScreen();
    this.levelDisplay();    
  },        

  levelDisplay: function() {  
    $('<div class="level_label" id="levelLabel">Level: </div> \
      <div class="level_value" id="levelValue">' + self.level + '</div>').appendTo('#game');
  },  

  clearScreen: function() {
    $('#game').html('');
  } 

};
```

but after run the game and press any keys on screen output next level sequence:

> 1, 2, 4, 16, 32, etc...

but i need follow sequence:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wyu8soj/

Comment: For some reason (as you may know) your `$(document).keypress(function())` defined in the game prototype is being called 2^n times. (as evidenced with a console.log, and of course the growth of the level variable).  Not sure why it is called extra times, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mutable data structure (`self.level++;`) and adding new `keypress` event on each `keypress` which leads to O(n^2) performance along with this strange bug.

First of all you should get rid of recursive, async calls to `Start`

```
Start: function() {
    this.levelInfo();

    $(document).keypress(function(){
      self.level++;
      // game body
      this.levelInfo();
    }.bind(this));
},
```

which will solve your current problem as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6wyu8soj/2/)

To avoid similar issues in future you can take a look at some immutable data structure like [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your keypress handler within Start, which will keep creating new keypress events. Try this instead:

```
var Game = function() {
  self = this;

  this.myMove = false;
  this.level = 1;

  $(document).keypress(function(){
      self.level++;
      // game body
      self.Start();
  });

  this.Start();
};

Game.prototype = {

  Start: function() {
    this.levelInfo();
  },     

  levelInfo: function() {
    this.clearScreen();
    this.levelDisplay();    
  },        

  levelDisplay: function() {  
    $('<div class="level_label" id="levelLabel">Level: </div> \
      <div class="level_value" id="levelValue">' + self.level + '</div>').appendTo('#game');
  },  

  clearScreen: function() {
    $('#game').html('');
  } 

};
```